# Incompatible types error when inheriting without specifying generic type of parent class

Tags: java, generics, types

This is regarding a puzzling "incompatible types" error which is produced when compiling the following piece of code, after a small modification.

Here is the content of a minimalist class, which compiles without problems in both javac and IntelliJ:

```java
public final class ChildClass extends ParentClass<Object> {
    public void method() {
        String value = stringList.get(0);
    }
}

class ParentClass<T> {
    protected final List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

After modifying the first line by removing `<Object>`, compiling it with javac produces the following error message:

```
ChildClass.java:6: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: java.lang.String
        String value = stringList.get(0);
                                     ^
1 error
```

A similar error message is produced by IntelliJ compiler as well.

Even though I understand the resulting code after the modification is not really recommended, I don't really understand why the String list is affected, although it should not depend on `T`.

Comment: Have you compiled it properly or you are hiding some important code . I guess this shouldn't be an error !

Comment: i just tried in eclipse. It gives me the same error as well .

Comment: The code compiles fine for me with javac and Eclipse. I could understand the problem if you used a raw type...

Comment: @PermGenError: Which version of Eclipse? It works fine for me...

Comment: @JonSkeet i tested in eclipse juno 4.2.0

Comment: @PermGenError: which jdk?

Comment: @Xie JDK version 1.7.0_17. BTW, i get the OP's error if i remove the generic declaration for the ParentClass. `public final class ChildClass extends ParentClass` this gives me OP's error

Comment: @PermGenError: That's exactly the OPs problem. Using <Object> as in the example code works for the OP.

Comment: same problem in java version "1.7.0_21"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.9) (7u21-2.3.9-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: I used 1.6.0_38 when I performed that test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Java Language Specification 4.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8):

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or non-static field (§8.3) M of a raw type C that is not inherited from its superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to C.

This means that all generic members of a raw type (= Generic used without type parameters) are considered raw.

You could fix your example:

```
public final class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    public void method() {
        String value = stringList.get(0);
    }
}

class ParentClass<T> extends NonGenericGrandParent {
}

class NonGenericGrandParent {
    protected final List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```